# beforeunload event of jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

These are my javascript function to check whether the user exiting the application with out saving the data

```
 <script src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="JScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="JScript2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.alerts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="jquery.alerts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    var isDirty;
    isDirty = 0;

    function setDirty() {
        var form = document.getElementById('form1');
        var inputs = form.getElementsByTagName('input');
        var e = document.getElementById("ddl");
        var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
            if (elems[i].type == 'text' || elems[i].type == 'checkbox' || elems[i].type == 'radio') {
                is_checked = elems[i].checked;
                is_checked1 = elems[i].checked;
                if (elems[i].value == '' && !(is_checked) && !(is_checked1) && strUser == '0') {
                    isDirty = 0;
                    //alert("In");
                }
                else {
                    isDirty = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $(document).ready(function f() {
        alert("In");
        $("#Button1").click(function () {
            if (isDirty == 1) {
                jConfirm('Can you confirm this?', 'Confirmation Dialog', function (r) {
                    if (r == true) {
                        //var link = '<%=btnDelete.UniqueID %>'
                        //__doPostBack('<%=btnDelete.UniqueID%>', "");
                    }
                    else
                        return false;

                });
                //return false;
                return false;
            }
            else {
                // __doPostBack('<%=btnDelete.UniqueID%>', "");
            }
        });
    });



</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(window).bind('beforeunload', function () {
        if (isDirty == 1) {
            alert("Hi");
            jConfirm('Can you confirm this?', 'Confirmation Dialog', function (r) {
                if (r == true) {
                    //var link = '<%=btnDelete.UniqueID %>'
                    //__doPostBack('<%=btnDelete.UniqueID%>', "");
                }
                else
                    return false;

            });
            //return false;
            return false;
        }
        else {
            // __doPostBack('<%=btnDelete.UniqueID%>', "");
        }
    });

</script>
```

This is my design

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Rqrd" runat="server" ValidationGroup="g" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
                    ErrorMessage="Required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chk" runat="server" Text="Check Me" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:RadioButton ID="radio" runat="server" Text="Radio" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="--Select--" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="One" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Two" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="Button2" type="button" value="Submit" />
            </td>
            <td style="display: none; font-size: 0px; width: 0px;">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Ok" ValidationGroup="g" OnClick="btn1_Click" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Cancel" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <%--<asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="Ok" onclick="btn1_Click" />--%>
</div>
```

On cancel click I am getting the alert I needed, the same is not getting when I close the tab where I went wrong can some one help me

This kind of scenario i need with my custom alert

http://www.mkyong.com/wp-content/uploads/jQuery/jQuery-stop-page-from-exit.html

[image]

Comment: Where is the value of 'R' coming from that you are using in the jConfirm Function?

Comment: It is an alert result which I used from here http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/12/jquery-alert-dialogs/

Comment: Also, is the Button Click Function and Before Unload Function supposed to be the same function? Do any of the three functions do what you would like them to?

Comment: Yes I would like to show exact replica of which I am showing on button

Comment: Check the code below, You should create the function only once, then call it with the different handlers.

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED** Removed two lines of testing code

```
 function checkit(){


    if (isDirty == 1) {

            jConfirm('Can you confirm this?', 'Confirmation Dialog', function (r) {

                if (r === true) {

                //var link = '<%=btnDelete.UniqueID %>';
                //__doPostBack('<%=btnDelete.UniqueID%>', "");

                }else{

                return false;

                }

            });

    return false;

    }else{

       // __doPostBack('<%=btnDelete.UniqueID%>', "");

    }

}
```

Then call the function with each of these?

```
 $("#Button1").click(checkit);

 $(window).bind('beforeunload',checkit);
```

Comment: Hi working but I am getting an alert as per image attached in my question i don't need that

Comment: I tried this but still when I am clicking on a button or closing the tab I am getting the message as per the image I posted

Comment: @ User I thought you want to get the alert to pop up on the button click and closing tab? That seems to be what your question was.  Please be more specific on what you want, thank you